# Dynamic initialize spring boot jpa repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a spring boot app with one web endpoint taking database name as a query param .

`GET /myapp/initdb?dbname=xyz`

I have one JPA repository

```
@Repository
public interface UserDataRepository
```

now i want to initialize the UserDataRepo based on the `dbname` inputed from the user.

So effectively i want to dynamically create JPA Repo during runtime based on different inputs from the user

How this can be achieved?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-abstract-routing-data-source